# SOLR 6.0.1 Unique Key change via API

Tags: solr

I'm attempting to modify the unique key in SOLR to accept a different value then the standard ID field with the 'managed-schema' in 6.0.1 but I can't figure out how to modify it.

Is there a way to change it via the api?

Answer (score 0):

Using API call you can only list uniqueKey , but there is no method to change it .